# How to test android CursorLoader with robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric, android-contentresolver, android-cursorloader

I want to test `CursorLoader` with **robolectric 3.0-rc2**

My test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(emulateSdk = 21)
public class MyCursorLoaderTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        final ContentProvider contentProvider = new MyProvider();
        contentProvider.onCreate();
        ShadowContentResolver.registerProvider(MyProvider.AUTHORITY, contentProvider);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCursorLoader(){
        CursorLoader cLoader = new CursorLoader(RuntimeEnvironment.application, SomeColumns.CONTENT_URI,
                SomeColumns.ALL_COLUMNS, null, null, null);
        Cursor c = cLoader.loadInBackground();

        Robolectric.flushForegroundScheduler();

        assertNotNull(c.getCount());
    }

    @Test
    public void testContentResolver(){
        final Cursor c = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getContentResolver().
                query(SomeColumns.CONTENT_URI,
                        SomeColumns.ALL_COLUMNS,
                        null, null, null);

        assertNotNull(c.getCount());
    }
}
```

`testContentResolver` succeeds, but `testCursorLoader` fails

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: The authority of the uri content://here.is.authority.of.MyProvider/SomeColumns_Table_Name does not match the one of the contentProvider: null
    at android.content.ContentProvider.validateIncomingUri(ContentProvider.java:1795)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.access$000(ContentProvider.java:90)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:202)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
    at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
    at here.is.project.package.name.controller.fragment.MyCursorLoaderTest.testCursorLoader(MyCursorLoaderTest.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:235)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:168)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

What have i to change in `testCursorLoader`?

Comment: It should not be necessary to create and register your content provider. Its already done by Robolectric. So delete your setIp() method. And instead of RobolectricTestRunner try RobolectricGradleTestRunner.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    final ContentProvider contentProvider = new MyProvider();
    ProviderInfo providerInfo = new ProviderInfo();
    providerInfo.authority = MyProvider.AUTHORITY;
    contentProvider.attachInfo(RuntimeEnvironment.application, providerInfo);
    contentProvider.onCreate();
    ShadowContentResolver.registerProvider(MyProvider.AUTHORITY, contentProvider);
}
```

Comment: not working.. when my app classes try to retrieve it with context.getPackageManager().resolveContentProvider(...) null is returned..